# Creating an XML document in PHP duplicates htmlentites

Tags: php, xml, dom

When trying to create an XML file in PHP using encoding ISO-8859-1 it appears that the & sign is converted into an HTML entity which causes an issue with an already converted string.

```
<CustomerDescription>The &apos;Sample&apos; product</CustomerDescription>
```

Becomes

```
<CustomerDescription>The &amp;apos;Sample&amp;apos; product</CustomerDescription>
```

This reads okay until either the loadXML() or the save() commands

```
$xml = "<CustomerDescription>The &apos;Sample&apos; product</CustomerDescription>";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$dom->save($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/folder/'.$filename);
```

Comment: Can't confirm that. Actually it replaces the entities with the single quotes: https://3v4l.org/lcU5n

Comment: When saving to a file and opened in notepad or a non html application it will do as described, otherwise when viewing in a browser it will always show the single quotes.

Comment: No, `save()` and `saveXML()` use the same serialization. If it passes trough an XML/HTML parser the entity will get decoded (that is what happens in the browser as well). The web application in the link shows the output as text not HTML - that is why you see the tags. I expect that you have some other code that replaces the character.

Comment: If you see here https://3v4l.org/G7eIs saveXML() keeps the &amp; but not the &apos; we need to be creating the excel with &quot;

Comment: Only if the receiving XML parser is broken. Quotes only need to be escaped in attributes if the are used as the delimiter of the attribute value. `&` is used for entities so it is escaped in the most places. Other characters depend on the encoding of the XML: https://3v4l.org/uGQSB

Comment: Thank you for your help, I know that they don't need to be escaped, our project is providing data to a large retailer for their website and they require the apostrophe to be escaped in the data feed which appears is not possible through the parsers (have tried simplexml as well). The only workaround we have is opening the xml in wordpad and replacing the quotes that way.

Comment: It is not the parser, but the serializer in this case. You could use string (or PCRE) functions on the generated XML string to account for that broken parser on the retailers side. Something like `file_put_contents($fileName, str_replace("'", '&apos;', $dom->saveXML()));`. Of course you need to be careful not to create invalid XML.